# Sql triggers for website

Tags: c#, database, web

I want to create a trigger for a column,
but as i am creating a web form i don't want to allow the user to see that id.
So when ever a user is added, I want to increment that id as us001, us002, etc.
How can I do that? I am inserting through c# but don't want to insert into this ID column... it should directly be inserted.

Comment: Without details, no one can help you.  What database?  Tables?

Comment: Welcome to SO - please use punctuation and proper words in your questions. As far as I can see you don't need a trigger just use a standard auto increment / identity column. Why do you need to store the prefix as part of the id?

Comment: cause i am creating a website where the user has to insert an image in that ...now the thing is i have created a separate table for images and i need specific id

Comment: still not sure why you need a prefix though. with us001, you will only have 999 users. why can't you use an identity field that automatically increments for you and use that id in the separate table? so create the user, return that new id and then save the image with the new id. not efficient, but it works. or create a stored proc that does all that for you in one database transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a trigger, you could return the userid generated by the database by adding SET @userid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()"; and from this you can create a a string

```
string generatedUserId = "us" + returnValue.ToString("000");
```

and then doing an update using the returned value id and the generated user id.

Here is a guide that may give you more of an idea: http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/02/16/2803.aspx

Hope this helps!